# iPhone cropped photos upload to Facebook uncropped

Tags: ios, photos, facebook

Steps to reproduce problem:

1. Crop a photo in the Photos app.
2. Open the FaceBook app and post the picture.

Once it has loaded you see the original un-cropped image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known behavior with the iOS photos app. When you try to share the image, It always uses the original version of the picture which means without the crop or the iOS camera filters.

### Solutions to cropping the photo on iOS

- Crop the picture using a third-party app and export the image to the photos app
- Crop the picture and take a screenshot of the photo and upload the screenshot.

Comment: Any recommendations for an editing app?

Comment: @hamishmcn You can try InstaSize - https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instasize-post-entire-photos/id576649830?mt=8&uo=4&at=11lMu5